# Extract specific information from text file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, text, extract

**Problem:**

I would like to extract specific information from a text file using PHP and create two arrays for the information.

**Example text file:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

1. Keywords for /Perspective should be in **first array**: skincover, intelligence and legs
2. Column keywords should be in **second array**: legs, skincover, weight, intelligence, speed

Column keywords that start with / should be ignored

**Code so far:**

```
<?php   
    $file = file('Creatures_rich.txt');

    foreach($file as $line_num => $line)
    {
        if (eregi("^/Perspective", $line))
             $perspective = explode(' ', trim(str_replace('/Perspective:', '', $line)));
    }

    echo "<xmp>".print_r($perspective, true)."</xmp>";
?>
```

**Output so far:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => skincover
    [1] => intelligence
    [2] => legs
)
```

How would I start with tackling the second array? Any ideas are welcome and any code example is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is format of your text data (excel, txt with delimeters)?

Comment: It is a text file (.txt) with tab delimeters. The screenshot is made by opening up the text file in Excel.

Comment: `Desired` output is very well presented, but `Required` code isn't.

Comment: Not sure I clearly understand. But I'm not looking for completed solutions but rather code samples and guidance to learn in the process.

Comment: Starting points: http://php.net/fgetcsv http://php.net/substr

Comment: Thanks, managed to solve first array. Any ideas how to get the keywords for second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Assuming that there is only going to be one line labelled `/Perspective:` and the first line with `\t` at the start is the column headings line...

#### Excessively commented (for clarity)

```
$perspectives = array();              //Initialise perspectives array
$columns      = array();              //Initialise column names array
$text_file    = fopen('./file', 'r'); //Open file to handle

while($line = fgets($text_file)){                        //Read file line by line
    if(strpos($line, '/Perspective:') === 0){            //Check if '/Perspective:' is at start of string
        $perspectives = explode(' ', substr($line, 14)); // Remove first 14 characters: /Perspective: 
        continue;
    }
    else if(strpos($line, "\t") === 0){ //Check if first char in line is \t
        $columns = explode("\t", 
                            preg_replace("#\t/.+#", '', substr($line, 1)) //Remove commented column names and first \t
                          );
        break; // Break while loop after column names row
    }
 }
```

#### Uncommented code

```
$perspectives = array();
$columns      = array();
$text_file    = fopen('./file', 'r');
while($line = fgets($text_file)){
    if(strpos($line, '/Perspective:') === 0){
        $perspectives = explode(' ', substr($line, 14));
        continue;
    }
    elseif(strpos($line, "\t") === 0){
        $columns = explode("\t", 
                            preg_replace("#\t/.+#", '', substr($line, 1))
                          );
        break;
    }
 }
```

#### Input file

```
/Purpose: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam, suscipit incidunt doloribus voluptatum dicta maxime accusantium animi eum vero eaque odit quae non quaerat possimus enim ad numquam consequuntur beatae.
/Origin: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, animi minus perspiciatis laudantium? Nostrum, aspernatur, sequi ratione assumenda fuga similique architecto deleniti sint recusandae voluptatibus numquam obcaecati ducimus eaque nisi.
/Rawdata: Unknown
/Perspective: skincover intelligence legs
/Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, libero, accusamus laboriosam modi voluptatem facere quod unde atque perferendis laborum nisi omnis nihil cum minima quaerat. Quia, quaerat ipsa molestiae.
    legs    skincover   weight  intelligence    speed   /something  /else
dog 1   1   1   1   1   1   1
pig 1   1   1   1   1   1   1
human   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

---

### Side note

I ran - out of curiosity - your code (**Code A**) against my code (**Code B**) to see which performed better.

#### Results

Time to execute:

```
Code A: 0.000108
Code B: 0.000044
```

*Code B* is `2.4545454545` times faster and does the entire operation `perspecitves` and `column names`

With out analysing the two codes *too much* I'd suggest the main cause for the difference is the ways in which we handle the file.

#### N.B.

I did run the comparison multiple times and the difference roughly ranged from `2.2x` to `2.7x`.

Also, the times are both *very small* so it's not like it's a big deal or anything...